# How to Use separate asp.net core web api in asp.net core Razor Page in Same Solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, razor-pages

I using Asp.net Core Razor Page as My webApp and asp.net Core api project as my api service Separate ... now how I can use apis in WebApp ... Thanks

Comment: Add New Project to solution, you can have two or more Web layer in solution.

Comment: If you want to just use the Web API then, you don't have to include it in the solution. You just have to call HTTP request whenever you need it. If need in one solution then refer TLDR; http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/e6557104-d06a-418c-a1a9-b8ce248f60b1.aspx

Comment: You can have WebApi Controllers and Razor pages in the same project. You can have them in separate projects if you want but they will work side-by-side as well.

Answer (score 2):

If the two projects have different originals, you need to [enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2#cors-with-named-policy-and-middleware).

Then you could use ajax or fetch api to call the web api in Razor Pages.

For example, assume Razor Pages has an original `https://localhost:44304` and Web Api `https://localhost:44362`

1.In Web Api project startup.cs

ConfigureService:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("MyPolicy",
            builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44304")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
        });
```

Configure:

```
app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

2.Razor Pages Index.cshtml:

```
<div>
<input type="button" value="Test"
        onclick="requestVal('https://localhost:44362/api/values')" />
<span id='result'></span>
</div>

<script>
function requestVal(uri) {
    const resultSpan = document.getElementById('result');

    fetch(uri)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => resultSpan.innerText = data)
        .catch(error => resultSpan.innerText = 'See F12 Console for error');
}
</script>
```

3.Click the button and display result

Comment: This was the most helpful answer I found. Want to add to it that you must call services.AddCors(...) after you've called services.AddControllers() and also call app.UserCors("myPolicy") after you've called app.UseRouting();